# Abstract class instantiate by own static method

Tags: java, class, static, abstract

```
DocumentBuilderFactory f = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance(); //
```

DocumentBuilderFactory is abstract class. newInstance is static method. Can't figure out how it works.
What happens?

I mean why it works... If I'm not mistaken we can't make instance of Abstract class.

Comment: Java?

What happens? You miss to give some context and the error message you see.

Comment: Actually it works. I don't understand why this expression works.

Comment: Related: http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=21 and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern

Answer (score 0):

You don't have an object of the DocumentBuilderFactory on the right side of the "=".

This is a factory method to create a `DocumentBuilderFactory` outside a constructor.

Answer (score 0):

this looks like some kind of singleton pattern, does the newInstance method return the EXACT same type, or does it return an actual concrete class that extends DocumentBuilderfactory? Is it really abstract, or does it have a private constructor?

Answer (score 0):

`DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance()` returns an instance of a concrete subclass of DocumentBuilderFactory. You can read its source [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilderFactory.java#DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance%28%29).

Answer (score 0):

newInstance is a static method, not a constructor, so it is free to create an instance of a concrete subtype of DocumentBuilderFactory. Which it does. I don't know the implementation,  but I assume it instantiates the default implementation of this class.